# How to sort ten coin for twenty single weightings?

Tags: sorting

We can sorting 10 coin for 20 weighting, don't it? We can know which of the two coins is heavier for one weighting. Any two coin have different weight.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm The efficient sorting techniques run in worst case scenario on the order of $n\log_2(n)$, so to sort ten coins, it could take upwards of $10\log_2(10)\approx 34$ weighings.

Comment: Did you use Google translate here? It is practically unreadable.

Comment: Vladislav, why don't you write the question also in Russian! I'm sure we can find a user who can provide a more fluent translation. Do keep the English version as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the question to be whether we can determine the order of the weights of $10$ coins using $20$ weighings.

The answer is no, since there are $10!=3628800$ different orders and only $2^{20}=1048576$ different results of the $20$ weighings. You need at least $22$ weighings (and probably quite a bit more).